# Filter through array of objects not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My objective**

I am trying to check if all instances of a `set` are owned by a particular player. Here is my attempt and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

So in my array of objects, I want to look at only City objects, then check the `set` property against the `set`(passed as a parameter in the function) I want to check, and finally check if every instance of that set has the same `owner`.

```
function test(){
    assignOwner();
    var set = "brown";
    var player = 1;
    if(doesOwnSet(set, player)){
    console.log("You own the" + set + "set.");
    }
    else{
        console.log("You dont own the set mate.");
    }   
}
function assignOwner(){
    positions[1].owner = 1;
    positions[3].owner = 1; 
}
function doesOwnSet(set, player){
    positions.filter(function(obj){
        return (obj.set === set;
    })
    .every(function(obj){
        return (obj.owner === player);
    })

}
```

** Array of objects I am trying to filter**

```
function Position (title, type, purchasable){
        this.title = title;
        this.type = type;
        this.purchasable = purchasable || false;
    }
    function Purchasable (prices){
        this.owner = "unowned";
        this.rating = 0;
        this.prices = prices;
        this.price = this.prices[this.rating];
    }
    function Corner (title){
        Position.call(this, title, "corner");
    }
    function CardPosition (title,type){
        Position.call(this, title, type);
    }
    function Tax (title,tax){
        Position.call(this, title, "tax");
        this.tax = tax;
    }
    function Utility (title, prices){
        Position.call(this, title, "utility", true);
        Purchasable.call(this, prices);
    }
    function Airport(title,prices){
        Position.call(this, title, "airport", true);
        Purchasable.call(this, prices);
    }
    function City (title,set,prices){
        Position.call(this, title, "city", true);
        Purchasable.call(this, prices);
        this.set = set;
    }
    positions = [
        new Corner("Go"),
        new City("Cairo", "brown", [60,2,10,30,90,160,250]),
        new CardPosition("Chest", "chest"),
        new City("Vienna", "brown", [60,4,20,60,180,320,450])
    ];
```

Comment: There are few syntax error, assuming it is a copy paste mistake... you need to return from the `doesOwnSet` method

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HW9tf/1/ - does this fixes your problem

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem. I need the return. Thanks Arun.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the value from the `doesOwnSet` method

```
function doesOwnSet(set, player) {
    return positions.filter(function (obj) {
        return (obj.set === set);
    }).every(function (obj) {
        return (obj.owner === player);
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HW9tf/)